# Chaining Multiple find statements in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I recently started development with Mongo DB and Mongoose ODM . I am having trouble to chain multiple find statements(find after a find is done).

Schema:

```
{
   UserId:
   LoginDays=[{
   date:
   action:
   }]
}
```

I want to check if userId exists if it does not create a new user, if it exists then find search the LoginDays array for the particular date , if entry is found reject the update else append to this LoginDays Array.

So Far I have tried

```
let userExists = false;
let dayExists = false;
User.find({ UserId: id })
  .then((a) => {
    if (a) {
      userExists = true;
      return a;
    }
  })
  .then((b) => {
    return b.find({ "LoginDays.date": date });
  });
```

I always get b.find is not a function, can anyone help me in this?

Comment: in case `a` is not found, you dont return anything, so `b` will be `undefined` in the next step. `undefined.find()` is not a function, because `undefined` has no functions. I can't comment on the mongoose part, because I never used it, but that might be one possible mistake

Comment: b is actually an object not undefined. I tried with a testcase where userId exists

Comment: make sure of that (log it). maybe your result is not as expected